# Why is McCoy so Racist Within an Otherwise Accommodating Universe?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

Based on a thought I had reading through some answers to this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/117488/36377), and many sentiments I've heard over the years about Gene Roddenberry's vision for a universe of total racial acceptance, cultural diversity, etc, why does McCoy always seem like such a flippin' racist toward Mr Spock?

I get that Kirk had a categorical mistrust of Klingons because a Klingon murdered his son, so—okay—*he* had an emotionally charged reason behind what he said in STVI which blinded him temporarily. Does McCoy have something in has past like this? Is he just a crusty old  Southern fossil? Is racism toward other species accepted with the general idea among humanity that they're only down with tolerance among other Earthlings? What's the explanation for McCoy's attitude

Comment: McCoy and Spock are actually good friends. It's like how you fight with your brother when you're a kid.

Comment: @Mithrandir No doubt, especially later on. But even amongst friends, he says what I would consider some  pretty over the line stuff. And there are times when it didn't seem all that much like joking.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76405/is-there-anything-more-to-the-way-others-mistreat-spock

Comment: While set in the 23rd century, it was written in the 1960s... and the language and characterisations would have been coloured by the writers of that time... we're having similar cringe moments watching old Bond movies (not exactly sci-fi - but similar issues of being written at a time with massively different social views)

Comment: Spock is similarly "racist", with continual jibes about McCoy's lack of emotional control.

Comment: @Richard Yeah, I guess McCoy is ironically just more memorable for it because he is so much more emotional about it. Still I think it's odd that I don't seem to recall him being that hostile to any other species based on ear-shape or blood-color. There was for sure explanation given for some Starfleet antagonism toward the Vulcan race in _Enterpirse_, but I was unsure if this was in anyway addressed in TOS, specifically in the way Kirk's racial mistrust was excused from being a part of the sort of racially accepting perfect Roddenberry universe.

Comment: Do you have specific examples of this racism? Maybe you can add these to the question so we all know we're on the same page.

Comment: @Paul Go to [the IMDB McCoy quotes page](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0001514/quotes) and Ctrl-F "green". I'll add to answer when not on mobile.

Comment: Wouldn't it technically speciesist?

Comment: @Vogie I do to know if it's meant to be a joke or you're just ESL, but no, "race "works here.

Comment: Because Spock was nothing but a hypocritical, condescending, green-blooded hob-goblin! Also, do you really think McCoy was more "racist" against Vulcans than Kirk was against Klingons or more so than the hob-goblin was against Humans?

Comment: @Richard: 'Spock is similarly "racist", with continual jibes about McCoy's lack of emotional control.' - Spock's emotional discipline is a chosen way of behaving, one that McCoy could in theory strive to achieve just as well. On the other hand, McCoy does not only refer to Spock's behaviour, but also openly occasionally expresses slurs about Spock's green blood or his pointed ears, which are natural traits. Furthermore, McCoy criticizes Spock's behaviour when he is annoyed by it; Spock criticizes McCoy's behaviour when he feels it negatively affects their work. I see quite a difference there.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper  - Ignoring the fact that Vulcan levels of emotional control are outside the capabilities of humans, Spock is quite happy to criticise humans for *being human*. That seems quite racist/speciesist to me. Heck, the whole Vulcan race seems to have a superiority complex.

Comment: @Richard: All right, that's more definitively racist then. Though of course, based upon Star Trek's depiction of aliens as "kind-of human", the science-fiction-y question of whether distinguishing racial traits would be something more acceptable in a society of actually different beings (i.e. not like with humans, who might have a different outward appearance, but who are essentially all human) is not discussed on Star Trek.

Comment: Let's see, we have racist klingons. Racist rokulans, cardadsians, Vulcan are a bit elitist... ferengi are consistently discriminated against bh the federation, (see ds9, not that it isn't deserved). What Maja you think that species is does not exist?

Comment: @GarretGang I don’t know what maja means, sorry for that. Googled it but didn’t get anything seemed right.  But I am kinda getting a “Why oughtn’t McCoy be excused as well?” vibe. If that’s the case, the history of southern US in which he was raised seems to me it shoulda galvanized him against such pettiness.

Comment: Is it actually racism, or only culturalism?  Isn't it the case that Vulcans *choose* to suppress their emotions while humans *choose* to express them.  That would make it simply a difference of opinion over what constitutes ideal behaviour.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Yes, he *is* a crusty old Southern fossil.

The **official Star Trek database** (at [**StarTrek.com**](http://www.startrek.com/)) uses your choice of words, almost verbatim, in describing McCoy's disposition:

> ***His temperament was sometimes argumentative, a cynic's outer crustiness masking deep caring beneath the surface.*** His "old South" roots led to the old-time physician manner of doctoring, with a Southern accent that was most apparent when under stress....McCoy played his role as psychologist expertly to the hilt — especially for the ship's two senior officers. As such an emotional watchdog he was not afraid to take on his captain, ***but it was his running battle of wits with Spock which became legendary.*** Spock showed his true feelings, though, as when inviting McCoy down to Vulcan for his "wedding" and in storing his katra with him before a known suicidal saving of their ship before the Genesis detonation.

([Source](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/mccoy-leonard))

In other words, McCoy and Spock have an underlying respect for one another, but McCoy displays a kind of biting wit and "crustiness" that mask his respect for Spock.

All in all, while humanity has evolved by McCoy's time to have eliminated most public displays of prejudice, this does not mean that every single individual adheres to this, and certainly not in equal measures.

Even by the 24th Century, humanity still has an underlying strain of prejudice.  From ["Encounter at Farpoint"](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/148.htm):

> **RIKER:** But your files, they say you're a —
>
> **DATA:** Machine? Correct, sir. Does that trouble you?
>
> **RIKER:** To be honest, yes, a little.
>
> **DATA:** Understood, sir. ***Prejudice is very human.***

Comment: I'm not convinced Spock was on the page as McCoy in this matter. In TOS: "All Our Yesterdays" Spock and McCoy are transported back into a planet's ancient history and Spock's mind begins reverting to a less disciplined state. McCoy throws a relatively mild jab at him: "You pointed-eared Vulcan!" Spock grabs him and replies, angrily: "I don't like that. I don't think I ever did, and now I'm sure." See http://www.startrek.com/watch_video/episode-preview-all-our-yesterdays

Comment: Granted this takes place in the middle of fight, but I was always under the impression that Spock put up with McCoy's language not because there a mutual agreement of it being friendly banter, but because it simply didn't trigger him emotionally (at least not seriously). But McCoy certainly could have had playful intentions in this matter.

Comment: I'm not sure the Data example is a good example. For instance, [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prejudice) describes *prejudice* as "an unfair feeling of dislike (...) especially when it is not reasonable or logical". IMHO, neither is it unreasonable to be unsure about what to expect on one's first encounter with a one-of-its-kind organism or device, nor is *being troubled* necessarily the same thing as *disliking*, or possibly even *expressing* that dislike.

Comment: I appreciate this answer very much. I'm curious why after a month there is so much activity on it in the last hour. Can you shed some light? Thanks!

Comment: I mean activity on the question. It's odd.

Comment: Someone posted a new answer so the question popped to the top of the page.

Comment: @thomas : I made a mental note to answer this about a month ago, but wanted to give it some extra thought first.  I had some time yesterday, and so posted this.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

In dramatic terms, McCoy can get away with being so irascible because he is the ship's medical officer. His devotion to the well-being of the crew (including Spock) provides a balance to his crusty exterior. The same balance would not work, for instance, in a science or weapons officer.